# Why was the scene with Biggs in A New Hope removed and never added again?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

I found this a while back, and it blew my mind.

It's a deleted scene with Biggs; it adds all the backstory about Biggs, who shows up in the last 30 minutes of the film and we have no idea who he is. It also adds a lot of character development for Luke; it explains almost everything about him, from clarifying what a hotshot pilot he is, slightly reckless, his feelings on the Empire. It also shows him as slightly immature, which since this is a coming of age story for Luke, really helps with the character development.

Why were these removed, and why were they subsequently ignored? It seems like they add a lot to the story.

Comment: I would have deleted it because of Luke's goofy hat and glasses. He looks like Gilligan.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Star Wars Wikia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Scenes_cut_from_Star_Wars),

> After Lucas's first screening of the rough cut of Star Wars in 1977, a fellow filmmaker jokingly accused him of producing "American Graffiti in space". Upon realizing that the story was being told through the droids' perspective and it was them leading things to Luke, Lucas took the footage out.

From this [Indiewire article](http://www.indiewire.com/2015/05/watch-17-minute-documentary-about-the-biggs-darklighter-deleted-scenes-in-star-wars-episode-iv-a-new-hope-264181/),

> It’s no wonder that the scene was cut. It’s too long, contains some awkward acting and on-the-nose writing, and the production design looks cheap even by “A New Hope” standards.

So, it seems that it was lengthy and slow-pacing. That's why this scene was cut out. And it was never added again in the other editions, but it has appearances in other mediums such as Star Wars "Lost Cut" and Star Wars: From the Adventures of Luke Skywalker 1977 novelization.

Here is a link to the documentary that got Tosche Station scene.

https://vimeo.com/126754777